# Keep getting error that says Server App Engine Standard at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, nullpointerexception, cloud

When trying to start a google app engine project in eclipse i keep getting an error saying Server App Engine Standard at localhost failed to start(error log below).

Has anyone come across this issue before and what was the cause of the issue.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory (file:/C:/Users/AppData/Local/google/ct4j-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar) to method java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Jan 05, 2020 3:13:54 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1316)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$CheckedMap.put(Collections.java:3638)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.setTimeZone(SharedMain.java:183)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.postServerActions(SharedMain.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:398)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
```

would be really appreciative of any advice anyone could give to help me solve this issue as time is definitely against me on this one.

edit: appengine-web.xml added below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <system-properties>
        <property value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" 
            name="java.util.logging.config.file"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: "*`... WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml' java.lang.NullPointerException`*" - Looks like a malformed `appengine-web.xml`. Could you post your `appengine-web.xml`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<sessions-enabled>false</sessions-enabled>

<runtime>java8</runtime>


-<system-properties>

<property value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" name="java.util.logging.config.file"/>

</system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>

Comment: Here it is, haven't touched the apengine-web.xml at all, would i need to add something to it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `xml` to the question.

Comment: "*`-<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">`*" - is the leading `-` a typo? If not: could that be the source of the exception? (There is a second leading `-` furhter down)

Comment: I think that may be just how it appears in browser - when viewed in notepad it doesn't appear with any dashes, will edit those out now.

Comment: Could you try to do it from the Cloud Shell? And from another machine? To discard any issue in your workspace.

Answer (score 7):

You're running with a Java 11 JVM, which isn't supported by the local development server.

This problem usually indicates that you don't have a Java 8 JVM configured.  You'll need to:

- Download and install a Java 8 JVM (for example, from [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net)).
- Add the JVM to Eclipse via *Preferences > Java > Installed JREs*; the *Search* button will usually just work.
- Mark this JVM as the default JVM for the *JavaSE-1.8*  profile in the *Execution Environments* pane.