# App engine local host not working on Eclipse after Java updates on 20/01/2021

Tags: google-app-engine

After a popup window has shown asks to confirm Java updates, the App engine could not be started again and Eclipse showing the following error:

> INFO: Overwriting system property key 'file.encoding', value 'Cp1252' with value 'UTF-8' from 'C:\Users\XXXX\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\XXXX\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
> at java.base/java.util.Properties.put(Properties.java:1334)
> at java.base/java.util.Collections$CheckedMap.put(Collections.java:3701)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.setTimeZone(SharedMain.java:183)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.SharedMain.postServerActions(SharedMain.java:152)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:398)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
> at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)

Comment: Have you tried [uninstalling](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/uninstalling) the Cloud Tools for Eclipse and try to [install it again](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart). What exact version of Java are you using? What is your OS? What is the version of Eclipse you are using?

Comment: Fixed by using a similar case on Stackoverflow
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098575/11005832)